# ¿Cómo filtrar con 2 condiciones en SQL server?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, phpmyadmin

Me gustaría realizar un filtro con 2 condiciones, la idea es que me muestre los Periodos que abarquen del P8 2021 en adelante es decir hasta el P8 2022. El código que uso es el siguiente y la tabla tiene estos valores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
SELECT * FROM TablaUtilidad
WHERE NumPeriodo > 7 AND NumAnio >= 2021
```

Pero el código solo me da los periodos mayores a 8

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es que quede así la tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Yo veo que la consulta que tienes no tiene errores, está arrojando los NumPeriodo >= 8 y que el año sea 2021 o superior.... cuál es el problema? o quieres solo los 2022?

Comment: NumPeriodo > 7 or NumAnio > 2021 prueba esto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas 2 condiciones unidas por un OR. Necesitas decir que traiga los periodos mayores dentro del año inicia y todos los periodos de los siguientes años. Entonces, quedaría así:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   TablaUtilidad
WHERE  (NumPeriodo > 7 AND NumAnio = 2021)
OR     NumAnio > 2021;
```